# Awk Search - Combined Character Classes in Same String

Tags: text-processing, awk

Good Evening,

I am attempting to utilize multiple character classes at the same time without success.  Given a column that contains the URI of HTTP traffic, I want the REGEX to identify lines that where the URI field contains a string of text 6-10 characters long that contains numbers **AND** lower case letters...at least one of each, but NOT upper case letters.

This search will NOT be bounded to a specific character or part of the string...

Test strings:

```
aasd4567
9f7g6s5df
0hjksdf73
123456789
12345/1234a
Wordswords
W0rdsW4rds
aasd4/567af
9f7g6s5dfasdf
0hjks/asdf
12345/1234asd
Wordswords12
W0rdsW4rds12312312
```

I had hoped I could utilize a little boolean with brackets, ie:

```
awk --re-interval '$1 ~ /([0-9]+&[a-z]+){6,10}/'
```

But that doesn't work.  And obviously, combining them won't work either because

```
awk --re-interval '$1 ~ /[a-z0-9]{6,10}/'
```

still returns strings without any numbers and without any lowercase letters.

I even tried to find ways to combine [[:lower:]] and [[:digit:]] but faced the same issue as the first example above.

I'm sure it's a super easy fix, what am I missing?  I'm not against using gawk/grep/sed/etc, whatever is the most efficient tool for this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use `match` first, then `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` to extract the matching string and then examine it for the presence of a digit AND a character, thus:

```
awk  --re-interval '{match($1, /[[:lower:][:digit:]]{6,10}/); 
  x=substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)}; x ~ /[[:lower:]]/ && x ~ /[[:digit:]]/' test_strings
```

Given your test strings this yields:

```
aasd4567
9f7g6s5df
0hjksdf73
9f7g6s5dfasdf
12345/1234asd
Wordswords12
W0rdsW4rds12312312
```

Comment: That actually works great, but I wonder if the match command might be too processor intensive.  Might there be a more streamlined way to do it?  The files I am looking through are 100k+ lines long...

Comment: @user112802, give it a shot, you will be surprised